# Backbone.history.start causes Security Error 18

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, html5-history

I have a problem with launching Backbone.history.start after router initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    app = new StyleRouter();
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: '/'});
});
```

It worked at start, but then I gave HTML code to another guy to rework it (he doesn't know, what special he did) and after that it causes "Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18" in Chrome, especially on line:

```
this.history.replaceState({}, document.title, this.root + this.fragment + loc.search);
```

in backbone.js.

Deep research and comparing with older code get nothing. What could it be?

Comment: A quick search shows this error is related to the HTML5 Canvas element.  Do you have any canvas elements?

Comment: I also found such material, but not, I am not using any canvas elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that there was a js code, that added an excess slash in location.hash. Still curious why it causes security error.